# using JSTL to build tables

Tags: optimization, jstl

I'm using this JSTL code to generate an HTML table. Every other row is given a different class so we can give the table stripes. I know we can do this easily with CSS3 but I have to support old browsers.

Anyway this is the code I use - it seems very heavy - is there an easier way to do it?

```
<c:set var="oddEven" value="true" />
<c:forEach var="row" items="${rows}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${oddEven}">
        <tr>
        </c:when>

        <c:otherwise>
        <tr class="odd">
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
            <td>${row.value1}</td>
            <td>${row.value2}</td>
        </tr>
    <c:set var="oddEven" value="${!oddEven}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${rows}" varStatus="status">
    <tr
      <c:if test="${status.count % 2 ne 0}">
        class="odd"
      </c:if>
    >
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I use `status.count` in this example; `count` counts the number of times the loop has executed, starting at 1. If you want the counting to start at 0, use `status.index`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<tr class="${(status.index % 2) == 0 ? 'oddRow' : 'evenRow'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JSP guru, but may be you could write a **custom jsp tag** to do this ?